# What style guide would be most helpful for formatting questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, formatting

The earliest examples of formatting are most likely to become the norm for the site.

Which of the following would be preferable, for example:

- Should there be a consensus on when to use bold face, bullets, italics, paragraphing, etc?
- What reasons are there for supporting that style?

vs

- *Should there be a consensus on when to use bold face, bullets, italics, paragraphing, etc?*
- *What reasons are there for supporting that style?*

Answer (score 6):

Having a style guide for posts in an SE network doesn't carry value, and make sense.

Some people would love to include lines from the internet in *italics*, and some would like to format them as quotes.

So, having a style guide wouldn't make it rigid for them, but atleast make them feel guilty if they aren't following it for writing their posts, which would damage the site in a way.

So, lets not have a style guide, please!